# Recover Filter Coefficients from Filtered Noise

Tags: filters, noise, impulse-response, deconvolution

I have a digital signal which may be represented as a pulse noise source filtered with an FIR (finite impulse response) filter. Suppose that the noise consists of discrete pulses (nonzero samples where most samples are zero), and there is an equal probability of a pulse at any sample (so for example the number of pulses in an interval follows the Poisson distribution). Further suppose the strength of each pulse is equal.

**Can the coefficients of the FIR filter be recovered from the filtered signal, and how?**

Now assume the noise is impulsive, but may be somewhat correlated with itself (it doesn't have perfect Poisson statistics). Also assume that the strength of each pulse may vary. Can the coefficients be recovered approximately if the exact distribution of noise is not known?

Noise source $N[i]$ where $i=0..n, N[i] = 1$ with some unknown but low probability $p$, 0 otherwise; each $N[i]$ is independent of other $N[i]$

Filter $F[k]$ where $k=0..m$, unknown, $m$ is much less than $n$

Signal $S[i]$ where $i=0..n$, $S = N * F$, where * is convolution

Given $S$, estimate $F$. $N$ and $p$ are also unknown.

To give this some practical background, the average period between noise pulses can be 20-40 samples, the FIR filter can have a few hundred nonzero coefficients (so the filtered signals resulting from each pulse overlap significantly), and the total signal is a few thousand samples.

**EDIT**: Some real-world data here: http://pastebin.com/N3LZU6vm  I think what you see at sample 780-810 is pretty close to the impulse response to a single impulse.  This is generated by noise fed into a complex resonator, whether the noise is impulsive as described above is not actually known but is physically plausible.

Some synthetic data here: http://pastebin.com/qTYLP5eA  This is generated from the following python code:

```
noise = numpy.where( numpy.random.rand(5000) < 1/20.0, numpy.ones(5000), numpy.zeros(5000))
filter = numpy.sin( numpy.arange(200) * 2 * math.pi / 11 ) * numpy.exp( - numpy.arange(200) / 30.0 )
signal = numpy.convolve( noise, filter )
for i in range(len(signal)): print int(signal[i] * (2**15)/ 3.0)
```

This creates a filter wavelet from a sinewave with period 11 samples and an exponentially decaying envelope, and noise where each sample has an independent 5% probability of being an impulse.

**EDIT**:  I think what I am looking for is very similar to what is involved in building an [autoregressive model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model) (AR).  There are slight differences in the formulation, for example AR is based on an IIR with lagged signal plus a noise term rather than FIR with lagged noise, and the noise is assumed to be Gaussian rather than impulses with Poisson distribution.  However I think AR proves that estimating a filter from filtered noise is possible, and in fact AR may just work for my problem.

Comment: This is done all the time in electrophysiology by a technique that is usually called reverse correlation (although it's a bit of a misnomer).  Whether you can reconstruct F (the kernel) depends on the characteristic of N.  What is the support of F?  I can work out the details for you another time.  No time now.  In fact, this looks like a physiology problem.  One cell fires randomly following Poisson.  It synapses into another cell.  You're recording from both cells.  You're looking for the EPSP/IPSP kernel.

Comment: @thang: thank you, fascinating! and no, this is from a different field.  From looking at the cases where pulses are far apart, support of F is 100-200 samples (a few times longer than average spacing between pulses), the envelope of F seems to be approximately exponentially decaying with time constant ~50 samples.

Comment: You have an interesting question. I need to think about it some more and try a couple things out. Do you happen to have any sample datasets that are representative?

Comment: @JasonR: I added some datasets. Let me know if you need more. Thanks!  P.S. Bounty coming up :)

Comment: can you post whatever statistical properties of n that you know?  if you know it's Poisson, post the estimated parameters.  otherwise, post sample n.  is it generated by an ergodic source?  what is the mean separation between the pulses?  or what is the separation distribution (exponential?)?

Comment: this problem is way under-determined.  i don't see how you can recover f from just s like that.  too bad stackexchange doesn't allow for bets.  otherwise, i would be willing to bet (>250 reputation pts) that it is not possible :p

Comment: I would tend to agree with thang in that you won't be able to just "solve" for the two signals that you want; there aren't enough constraints to get an exact solution. However, you may be able to *estimate* the two under the constraint that the input signal $N$ is sparse.

Comment: if you assume n is sparse with no overlap at all, you can get it up to a constant amplitude and shift.  if you assume n is sparse with no overlap and is only 0 and 1, then you can get it up to shift in time (this is stated in my answer).  judging from the sample data, this is clearly not true.  going through the test trace, there is completely no "quiet" period suggesting that there is absolutely no area where there is no overlap.  i.e. it's not just that n is not sparse.  it's that n is no where sparse.  either that or noise is super high.  in either case, you're SOL based on the test data.

Comment: also, under the assumption that n is sparse with some overlap, but at least there are areas in which f sits isolated but buried in noise.  in this scenario, then motifs of the form $\alpha f + noise$ would exist throughout the trace.  no such motif exist based on my prelim analysis, but i guess it is possible to play with parameters in the search.  regardless, if you need to go that far to get things to work, the result would be pretty unreliable.

Comment: @thang: I understand why you think this problem is underdetermined.  Certainly as a system of linear equations, it is.  However, we do know two things which are huge constraints on the possible solutions: that N is random and all N are drawn from the same distribution; and that F is the same throughout.  My intuition says this is sufficient to estimate F quite well;  I just don't know *how* :)

Comment: @thang: see above about autoregressive analysis.  It seems this is not a completely new problem :)

Comment: I've built AR and ARMA models before.  It is not what you want.  AR more or less assumes IIR filter.  Much in the same way that given an IIR filter, chances are that you can solve the recurrence relation via z-transform (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423832/can-not-figure-out-complexity-of-this-recurrence/14424445#14424445) and the output is pretty much drives itself.  AR is used to model natural processes (and sometimes artificial IIR filtered data).  The assumptions in AR and ARMA clearly do not hold true here.

Comment: So one possible approach is basically what I stated above.  To search for motifs in the data of the form $\alpha f + noise$.  In fact, this doesn't work.  I've played with parameters.  I've also used a relatively smart machine learning clustering to try to isolate motifs (SVM, k-means, etc.).  No motifs show up!  The main reason is because sparseness constraint does not hold!  When you have 5% pulse probability, that means 1 out of 20 samples is a pulse.  There is very little chance of getting any sparse pulse spread 200 (support of f) samples apart.

Comment: In fact, if you have a non random and repetitive input, then AR, ARMA, markov or any output-output dependent type model can have a good chance of working, but that is clearly not the case here.

Comment: One other thing to try is to suppose you have M pulses out of P samples.  Then there are (p choose M) ways in which they can be placed.  You can artificially place the pulses and compute the "reverse correlation" by inverting the toeplitz etc etc.  After doing all of that, you get a kernel f and an error e.  So basically for each configuration of pulses, you get an error $e_i$ for i=1,2,...,(p choose M).  The one with the minimal error is your solution.  The problem is that you will find that the solution is not unique!  It is way over determined, and provably so.

Comment: For these reasons, I would be willing to bet all my reputation points if someone can get it :p  Sometimes intuition can be wrong.  Consider for example the question of whether there are more integers than positive integers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an interesting problem.  What you have there is what's known as a [blind deconvolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_deconvolution) problem.  These are well known "hard" problems, but not necessarily impossible.  Finding an algorithm to solve it relies on using some prior knowledge you have about the filter or the noise source driving it.

It's an ill-posed problem mathematically, so if there is a solution, there's no guarantee it's unique.  In other words you might get a set of FIR coefficients that seem to fit the data, but it's not guaranteed that they are the "right" coefficients that model the filter well in the real world.

Having said that, I've tried using the [EM algorithm](http://melodi.ee.washington.edu/people/bilmes/mypapers/em.pdf) and got some promising results.  It's not perfect, but I think it's possible to get a solution.

I've changed the model slightly so that $$S = N*F + v$$where $v$ is Gaussian noise with some unknown variance.  If we find a good solution, this variance should end up being small compared to the signal.

In the EM algorithm you need some hidden variables: in this case, $N$, and some unknown parameters.  Those are $F$, $\sigma^2$ the unknown noise variance, and $p$ the probability of $N_i\in{0,1}$ being equal to one.  This is the prior distribution on $N$.

The trick to it I found was to use the [alternative description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#Alternative_description) of the EM algorithm where the hidden variables are described by an approximating distribution $q$.  We want $q$ to approximate the posterior distribution given the observations and the parameters: $p(N|S,F,p,\sigma^2)$.  This almost certainly doesn't factorize as a product of probabilities $q(N_0)q(N_1)...q(N_n)$ so this is an approximation.

In this case $q$ consists of $q_i$ for $i=0..n$ where $q_i$ is the probability that $N_i=1$ under this approximating distribution.

The EM algorithm is an iterative one, where each iteration involves alternately updating $q$ based on the current value of the parameters, then updating the parameters based on the current value of $q$.

I haven't said anything about $m$ yet: it's unknown, but if we make it too big, the extra FIR coefficients should be set to near zero.  These might be at the start or the end, it just depends where the algorithm decides to converge to.

I simulated some data of my own with the same pulse shape as in your synthetic example, with these results.  The true value of $m$ was 200, so I ran the EM algorithm with $m=400$ to see how it did.  I made $S$ 10000 samples long, to be sure I had enough data.  The result came out at about half the amplitude of the original, and as explained above there are some extra coefficients at the start and the end, but shifting and scaling to compensate you can see that it got the shape of the impulse response fairly accurately:

[image: simulated data, 1000 samples]
Zooming in on the middle section:
[image: simulated data, 1000 samples, around the peak impulse response]

From your file synthetic_data.txt I got something similar:

[image: result estimated from synth_data.txt]

[image: result from synth_data.txt, zoomed]

As it stands it seems to be overestimating $p$ i.e. putting in too many impulses and underestimating the magnitude of the FIR coefficients to compensate.

Now on test_data.txt, the algorithm gave this impulse response:

[image: impulse response estimated from test_data.txt]

It's harder to tell how well the algorithm has done this time because we don't know the true impulse response.  One thing we can do it try to reconstruct $S$ from our estimate $\hat F$ and some estimate of $N$.

I've used $q_i$ to estimate $N_i$ by thresholding: if $q_i>0.5$ I put $\hat N_i=1$ as my estimate of $N_i$, otherwise I use $N_i = 0$.

Convolving that sequence $\hat N$ with $\hat F$ gave a decent match to $S$.  I've zoomed in on a typical short subsequence so you can see the detail:
[image: typical section of the reconstructed sequence]

One caveat I have is that the rate of impulses seem a bit high: about 10% of the reconstructed $\hat N_i$ samples were equal to $1$, which is more than your 1 in 20 to 40 estimate.

But overall I think that's doing well for a blind deconvolution problem, so I'd say it's doable with an EM algorithm or something similar.

There are quite a few other algorithms for blind deconvolution, see the references, and one of the others might be better for you.  Variational Bayesian EM would be worth trying, and there are others which might have some advantages in other ways.  It always depends on how much prior knowledge you have, and on other constraints like runtime.

The code below works in Octave: I haven't tried it in Matlab (because I don't have a licence) but it should work in Matlab too.  Very much prototype code, don't rely on it for anything critical without some more work (sanity checking, catching potential divide-by-zeros etc.)  Runs in about 30 minutes on my two-year-old laptop.

Thanks for uploading the example datasets, which was very useful.

```
function [Fhat,q] = blindDeconvImpulseNoise(filename)

% Load data from file
S = load(filename);
% Renormalize
scaleFac = sqrt(mean(S.^2));
S = S/scaleFac;

% Estimate (assume filter has less than 400 taps)
tic();
[Fhat,q] = estimate(S,400);
toc();

Fhat = Fhat * scaleFac;

end


% Run the estimation: the EM algorithm
% (see ftp://ftp.cs.toronto.edu/pub/radford/emk.pdf)
function [Fhat,q] = estimate(S,m)

L = length(S);

% Initial values
q                      = ones(L+m-1,1)/2;

% Fhat is the estimated filter.  
Fhat = zeros(m,1);
Fhat(max(1,floor(m/2))) = 1;

% Initial values of the scalar parameters: noise variance and 
sigmasq_hat = 1;
Rhat = 0.01;

last_sig = inf;

starttime = now;
timeout   = 1800;

while 1

  % Estimate hidden variables
  % Start by converting hidden states into 
  Fmtx  = getConvmtx(Fhat,length(q));
  Fmtx  = Fmtx(m:end-m+1,:);

  for i=1:length(q)

    ind = max(1,i - m):min(i+m-1,size(Fmtx,1));
    ind2 = max(1,i - 2*m):min(i+2*m-1,size(Fmtx,2)); 
    ind2 = ind2(ind2~=i);
    Fi = Fmtx(ind,i);
    resid_less_i = S(ind) - Fmtx(ind,ind2) * q(ind2);
    l = (Fi'*Fi - 2*Fi'*resid_less_i)/(2*sigmasq_hat) ...
        - log(Rhat) + log(1-Rhat);

    q(i) = 1./(1+exp(l));

  end

  qmtx                  = getConvmtx(q,m);
  qmtx                  = qmtx(m:end-m+1,:);

  % Estimate parameters
  Sigma                 = (qmtx'*qmtx) ;
  % Matrix diagonal
  Sigma(1:m+1:end)      = sum(qmtx);
  % Store common term Q'*S
  NS                    = (qmtx'*S);
  % Pseudoinverse estimate of Fhat
  Fhat                  = Sigma\NS;
  % Noise estimate, based on error residual
  sigmasq_hat           = (S'*S - NS'*Fhat)/length(S);
  % Pulse rate estimate
  Rhat                  = mean(q);

  if abs(sigmasq_hat - last_sig) < 1e-10
     % No change on this iteration: stop here
     break
  end
  last_sig = sigmasq_hat;

  if 24*60*60*(now - starttime) > timeout
     warning('Timeout!');
     break
  end
end

end


function Nmtx = getConvmtx(N,m)

Nmtx = zeros(length(N)+m-1,m);

for idx=1:m
    Nmtx(idx:end-m+idx,idx) = N;
end

end
```

Comment: If you can provide links to the images, then someone else can edit your post to add them in. I'm interested to see your results.

Comment: Sadly they thought of that too: new users can't link to things either

Comment: @Gruntled: This is amazing!  Probably the most epic stackexchange answer I have ever seen.  Thank you.  I'll have to read up on the algorithm and get your code running, but I think this does the job nicely.

Comment: Great to see someone could pull together a suitable answer.  @AlexI I would love to know how this goes, so a follow up post would be greatly appreciated.  I have a kind of similar issue I am working on.  In my case, I'm trying to locate the time separation between impulses very precisely.

Comment: This is phenomenal!  Ok @AlexI, I owe you some rep points :p  I am very surprised that EM can converge with so little information given that there are so many solutions that would generate the same data points.  Remark then that you may be able to impose additional regularization constraints by using MAP - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation

Comment: @thang: No points for me, but give some to Gruntled if you want :)  And thanks for the MAP suggestion too - I've been reading the blind deconvolution literature but couldn't immediately think of a way to apply it.

Comment: @AlexI, well if SE would allow a way to transfer points... :p  I've used semi-blind deconvolution, but I thought that there is no way it would converge given the limited information, and there are clear "confusion" scenarios.  Typically, more assumptions are used (e.g. the form of F, which is commonly used to de-blur images).  One thing you can do to increase the chances of convergence is to use MAP and add (as prior) regularization constraints using the form of F (e.g. if you know it's a decaying exp), the sparseness of N, and even statistical prop of the underlying RV that generated N.

Comment: Wow, I don't think I've ever seen such a positive response for an answer.  Thanks everyone, and @AlexI I'd really appreciate knowing how well this works in practice.  thang's suggestions of MAP estimation and a sparseness prior on N sound like good ideas too, especially as EM might not be giving sparse enough answers.  Would be interesting to do a side-by-side comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so for the discrete case, this is actually pretty simple.  It comes out to a big matrix equation.

Basically, you have that:

(1) $s = n * f$

(notice that the conventional way to write this is $s = n*f$ but you can just as well transpose as convolution is commutative)

as you have stated.  In fact, this is really simple :p  I have used lower case letters to represent your variables.  This is because they are sequences, represented as vectors.  I am reserving uppercase for matrices.

Define $N$ to be (the transpose of) the [Toeplitz matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) of $n$ given by:

$ N =
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
n_1 & 0 & . & 0 \\
n_2 & n_1 &  . & 0 \\
 .  & . & .  & . \\
n_m & n_{m-1} & . & n_1 \\
 0  & n_m & . & n_2 \\
 .  &  .  & . & . \\
 0  &  0 &  0 & n_m \\
\end{array} \right]
$

So equation (1) becomes

(2) $s = Nf$

just a matrix multiplication.  In this equation, you know $s$ and $N$ and want to find $f$.

You probably have a lot of input and output samples compared to the size of the filter, so the length of $s$ is a lot bigger than $f$.

From linear algebra, recall that if rank(N)>length(f), then you can completely reconstruct $f$ from $n$ and $s$.  Otherwise, you can't.  In this case, you can shuffle things around, but there's always going to be missing information.

So how do you solve for $f$?

It's just a simple over-determined matrix equation.

One way is to use least square by evaluating $ argmin_f||s-Nf||$.  There are many ways to do this, and it is the topic of several chapters in numerical methods.  I won't go into that.

EDIT:

as per discussion below, it seems I misread and n is also unkown.  In this case it is impossible to recover f.  This is a case of system identification.  See here [Get an input signal from LTI system output, find impulse response](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/7594/get-an-input-signal-from-lti-system-output-find-impulse-response) for a brief discussion about it.

This issue is really quite simple.  I say c = axb (multiply, not convolution) and then tell you that c is 10.  what is b?  There is no way to tell.

Your specific scenario is actually worse than that.  It is difficult to even make a connection between the distribution of s and n.  This is primarily because output s  generated by convolving n with f converts most distributions into something that looks normal (recall the central limit theorem), assuming that n is generated by an iid process.

If you know that $n$ is sparse and can guarantee that the pulses are always farther apart than the support of f, then just model this into the formula.

And in fact, you don't have to do anything.  whenever $s>0$, the portion of $s$ in the vicinity that is $>0$ a shifted version of your $f$.  Of course, there is no way to know the degree of shift.

If you know that there is a small probability of overlap between the pulses, then what you can do is generate $f_1$, ... $f_p$ for each time $s>0$.  Most of them will look similar (plus noise), and the rest will look like a shifted sum of the majority.  What you can do, then is, out of the $f_j$, take the ones with smallest support, shift them so the $L_2$ norm is minimal, and average the shifted versions them together.  This gives you an estimated $f$ (within shift in time) from pulses that are far apart.  You can similarly model 2, 3, 4, etc. overlapping pulses...

Comment: thank you, this is interesting.  the problem is that N is unknown also...   N is a random signal, one can to some extent guess where the nonzero elements (pulses) are from the highest peaks in S but some of those can be caused from superposition of the impulse responses from several earlier peaks as well.  the solution you have is great for known N and unknown F, but what we have here is independeltly random unknown N as well as unknown F.

Comment: then you can't recover anything.  more unknown than variables.  even if n were known, you can't guarantee to be able to recover f all the time.  if you don't known n, then all bets are off.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ideas (not solutions)

First, imagine what would happen if you're noise was instead a periodic impulse at the average period between samples (lets say a pulse every 30 samples).  You would end up with a periodic sequence.  Can you try averaging your data, perhaps using 30 sample long windows in such a way that the result, given sufficient sample size approaches this periodic response.  Once you have this "average" response signal, find the DFT over one period of the signal.  Then interpolate the DFT points to prvide enough detail (points/bins) to exceed the estimated support of F (say 200 bins).  Then take the IDFT of the result.  The reslult will provide an approximation of the FIR "filter" coefficients.

Second you can look into research on the representation and recovery of signals using random sampling.  This is a different problem, but the techniques may be useful for the problem you are trying to solve.  Here is a link to an article:  http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/22215/0000648.pdf;jsessionid=92ABBC582E3D6909A24775F88D6543D2?sequence=1

Comment: the paper you quoted is absolutely unrelated as you pointed out.  it is actually on extending the sampling theorem to irregular sampling.  that aside, there is also a set of other papers on system identification using random input, but they all assume you know the input, and they control it to make well behaving Toeplitz matrix.  1 point out of every 30 samples means the signal has a 30 sample period.  this actually represents a low freq limit on recoverability of your filter and actually is reflected by rank of the Toeplitz of this signal.

Comment: The general problem is to recover a signal from random views of that signal.  I would think that the research on system ID from random inputs would also be relevant here.  Why not post a link to an example or two that at least loosely fit the problem at hand.

Comment: Did you read the paper?  it is to reconstruct the analog signal from random sampling of the signal.  standard sampling is periodic.  the research on system ID all end up with equation (2).  they control the input to make well behaving matrix N.  i suspect that OP has no control over the input.  otherwise he would know what it is, which he doesn't.  this is where the hangup is.  otherwise this problem is just standard system id.  standard system id assumes you know n and s (sometimes have control over n).  what i posted is actually from standard id.  in this problem, you don't know n.

Comment: Yes I did read that paper and several others on recovering signals from random samples.  I well understand where the hang up is.  You won't find a solution using deterministic methods.  There may not be a ready made textbook solution that you can apply to this problem.  Probably why it was posted in the first place.  Since no one has offered up a solution, I am simply making a suggestion to broaden your horizons.  It could spark an idea.

Comment: I see.  I just wanted to remark that his issue is not from sampling.  Random sampling has nothing to do with it, although it is a cool idea, and has a lot of implications in other areas.  The specific problem that is presented here is not solvable and provably so.  Basically, you're asked to find the solution to an under-ranked equation.  It's mathematically not solvable.  Usually what this means is that there is additional information from context (specific application) that OP is not disclosing.

Comment: Agreed.  A direct approach for an exact solution is not possible with the information at hand.  This may be the nature of the problem, in which case you are searching for a method of approximation, most likely involving a statistical approach.

Comment: I agree, and I think that what approximation (which would in effect be filling in data) is appropriate depends on the application, which is not stated.

Comment: @BruceZenone: Guys, thank you for the great discussion.  I've posted some sample data above.  As you can see there appears to be coherence on the very short time scales, and even exactly repeating waveforms.  The noise source however destroys any coherence on longer time scales.  I think this is the key, the resulting signal is mostly not noise, it just has "phase noise" in discrete jumps.  Spectrum is pretty wide: seems like Fourier transform doesn't see most of the structure.  Agree this has to be an approximation, but how?...